# Cross-compiling with mingw

Tags: mingw, cross-compiling

I have code which need to be compiled via mingw on a 64bit Intel machine (windows 7). It then has to run on a 64bit AMD virtual machine (windows 7). At the moment it works on the Intel but not on the AMD VM. Do I need to cross-compile it to make it work? If so how would I go about it? I'm not so familiar with mingw.

Comment: What you're describing isn't cross-compiling. You just need to make sure that you properly install the program you compiled *and* all of its dependencies onto the AMD VM. It might help if you actually told us exactly what you mean by 'not [working] on the AMD VM'.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by running `./configure` with the `--enable-runtime-cpudetect` flag.